# Group two lists by index using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to group two lists together but only with linq statements. No extra variables or loops.

```
IEnumerable<string> keys = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "D" };
IEnumerable<string> values = new List<string>() { "Val A", "Val B", "Val C", "Val A", "Val B", "Val C", "Val D" };
```

Result should be like:

- A

  - Val A, Val A
- B

  - Val B, Val B
- C

  - Val C, Val C
- D

  - Val D

I tried .ToLookup() but I never used that before so I am stuck.

How to achieve this just by using linq.

Comment: What type is the result?

Comment: @TimSchmelter it should be a grouping thingy with keys and values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
keys.Select((k, idx) => new { k , idx })
.GroupBy(x => x.k)
.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(x => values.ElementAt(x.idx));
```

It could be more efficient if you turn the values into a list or array, then you can use *indexer* instead of `ElementAt`.

Comment: @devhedgehog Actually I think you're wrong about that.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative, that isn't O(n^2):

```
var grouped = keys
    .Zip(values, (k, v) => new { k, v })
    .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.k)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(kvp => kvp.v));
```

Note that the dictionary won't preserve the order of the keys; you can use this instead if you'd rather:

```
var grouped = keys
    .Zip(values, (k, v) => new { k, v })
    .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.k, kvp => kvp.v);
```

This will let you iterate through the keys in the order in which they appear in the input, at the expense of not being able to look up via a key.

Answer (score -1):

```
IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> result = 
    keys.Distinct().ToDictionary(x => x, key => values.Where(value => value.EndsWith(key)));
```

Comment: It should be based on index number and not on content

Answer (score -1):

```
        IEnumerable<string> keys = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "D" };
        IEnumerable<string> values = new List<string>() { "Val A", "Val B", "Val C", "Val A", "Val B", "Val C", "Val D" };

        var x = from string key in keys
                join string val in values on key equals val.Substring(val.Length - 1, 1)
                select new
                {
                    key,
                    val
                };
```